# Jquery addClass when page loads specific URL

Tags: jquery, url, hash

I'm trying to add a class only when the page loads with a specific URL (example.com/#test) but can't seem to get it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(window.location.href === "https://example.com/#test"){
    $('.test').addClass('display');
  } else {
    $('.test').removeClass('display');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `window.location` object has a `hash` member, which contains all charatcers from the `#` mark on. 
Try: `window.location.hash.indexOf("test") > -1` as your condition.

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.hash.indexOf("test") > -1){
        $('.test').addClass('display');
    } else {
        $('.test').removeClass('display');
    }
});
```

Comment: When the page loads, nothing happens. But if I add link with "#test" as the href, and then load the page without the hash (example.com). Click that link, then "tabindex="-1" is added to the div. Nothing is added to the class. Now, if I load the page with that hash (example.com/#test) nothing happens either to the class and the "tabindex="-1" isn't there as well.

Comment: Changed "$(document).ready(function()" with "jQuery(document).ready(function($)" and it works. Thanks

Comment: I see,you must be on WordPress or something with similar restrictions to the `$` function.